# Does parcel fabric have topology built in?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, topology, parcel-fabric

I am a little confused on parcel fabric. Does parcel fabric have a topology built in already? OR are you supposed to create a topology for your parcel fabric?

Just a little background is that I have a parcel fabric that I already created that I have been drawing parcels in from scratch.

Basically I am asking do I have to create a topology (if yes HOW) or will the parcel fabric make sure the parcels have no overlaps/spaces, etc

Answer (score 1):

You don't HAVE to create topology for a parcel fabric but it would be a good idea, that way you can reconcile any gaps that are in between the polygons you've drawn in. The process of doing so can be found [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-parcels/loading-data-to-the-parcel-fabric.htm).

Comment: So just to clarify.... Do I create a topology and choose the parcel lines and parcel polygons? Again I have already drawn some parcels.

Comment: Courtney Pete says to you that when you digitized map objects, you could make mistakes, for example, self-intersections, non-opening lines, etc. Then he wanted to tell you that topology is the process of putting objects in order, namely, finding errors and correcting them, so special tools are created for this process, now it’s clear ...

Comment: I understand that Pete is saying to create a topology... I am now asking about the typology. I am confused about how to create a typology since I have already created a parcel fabric and already have data in it.

Comment: Try to carefully read my 1 sentence. Perhaps there were errors in your data in the topology, and perhaps not ... How to check this statement, for this you run your data through the tool for errors, and if errors are found, use topology tools, for example, to tie a point of one object to a point of another object etc ...

Comment: Courtney, Please follow the link I posted to ESRI support that outlines how to load a topology into a parcel.  I didn't want to reinvent the wheel so I linked to their guide.

Comment: I see you asked this question again and it was, justly, downvoted.  Stack Exchange is here to help you with specific questions, not providing you a step by step workflow for how to complete a task.  I took a 16 hour course on how to work with parcel fabrics through ESRI, so there really is no way to provide you with anything simpler than what is already provided.